# (Polymer) <core-animation-pages> content bleeding outside main DIV when using "slide-from-right"

Tags: javascript, polymer, css-animations, web-component

Here's a brief video I recorded showing this behaviour: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j20zaw2h472l9iu/polymer-slide.mov

I've succesfully implemented core-animation-pages on my web app. I've got 3 differentes div's that transition using the slide-from-right animation with no problem, except that in desktop view the content doesn't "hide" within the main div (white color) and instead is seen on top of the gray background for about a second. This is not visible on mobile or tablet view.

Is there anything CSS-wise I need to write to avoid this?

Here's my code:

```
<core-toolbar class="medium-tall">
<div flex class="title">Elementos del lenguaje visual</div>
<div class="bottom fit" horizontal layout>
  <paper-tabs flex noink selected="{{selected}}">   
    <paper-tab>LÍNEA</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>FORMA</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>COLOR</paper-tab>        
  </paper-tabs> 
</div>
</core-toolbar>

  <div class="{{ {scroll: !wide} | tokenList }}" layout vertical flex>
  <core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{selected}}" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{done}}" transitions="slide-from-right" layout flex>      

    <div id="linea">
    <div id="bidimensional">
    {{CONTENT}}
    </div>
    <div class="separador"></div>
    <div id="tridimensional">
    {{CONTENT}}
    </div>   
    </div>

  </core-animated-pages>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden` on your core-animated-page so as a container it will hide any overflow content when you animate the page inside the container.